# Bug with user page formatting for long locations

Tags: bug, status-completed, markdown, users-page, location

On the [user page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users?tab=reputation&filter=all), profile information doesn't render properly when the location is too long:

[image: That's TheTXI for ya! Still screwin' things up even though he ain't been here since '09!]

Those lush green fields and unfashionable galactic arms are playing hell with the formatting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

width: auto was not good there.