# Long user locations without a space causes the "user page" to display weird

Tags: bug, design, users-page

Earlier today, as I was settling into my daily morning routine of "Answer questions on meta while drinking coffee", I saw a strange bug on the user page. There is a huge block of whitespace through the middle of the users page!

[image]

[Link for the curious.](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/users)

I thought this was weird, but when I scrolled down, it all made sense.

[image]

Now, to be fair, it's a little bit silly and immature of this user to pick a location like

```
/root/x/x/x/x/x/x/x/x/x/x/x/x/x/x/x/...
```

But there's nothing stopping them from doing this anyway. Can we make this get cut off at some length? Maybe change it to ellipses when it gets too long, kinda like this:

[image]

IMO this looks much better.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84151/bug-with-user-page-formatting-for-long-locations http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/231981/overly-long-user-location-entry-breaks-mobile-users-view

Comment: @random I do not believe this is a duplicate since one of those is about mobile, and the other one is [tag:status-completed]. Either way, it seems like this has caused a fair number of issues.

Comment: Just reproduced this; https://i.stack.imgur.com/mykCx.png | https://i.stack.imgur.com/I8Evr.png | https://i.stack.imgur.com/d8Kop.png

Comment: @Mithrandir unfortunately bounty can’t speed up a bug fixing.

Comment: @alexolut usually not but it just gives a better feeling that we really did everything we can do. :)

Comment: This is one of the few bugs that really made me laugh. Interesting!

Answer (score 2):

On the old EL&U theme, this "old" problem persists but even worse. The location's uninterrupted name overlaps and extends into the territory of other users.

> [image]

However, on the **[new theme](https://english.stackexchange.com/users?tab=newusers)**, this bug seems to have been fixed

> [image]

Still... there should be a limit as to the number of characters a location has, imaginary or real.

Comment: Intervention! O:

Answer (score 1):

On the Wikipedia webpage [List of Long Place Names](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_long_place_names) there are legitimate names of up to 85 characters with the top half dozen all being longer than the length you suggest to truncate to.

The user above that @flawr also has a long place name, but it's not their longest line. Other users, like @user2428116 (to the right) have no location and use less vertical space.

Perhaps we should allow wrapping, instead of restricting to a single line 3 could be allowed.

A background process could determine if the text matched a know place and restrict the user to a reasonable length while legitimate names could be afforded a bit more space.

That walks the line against discriminating where people claim to be from, censorship and reasonableness.

A bit of vertical whitespace wouldn't be nearly as bad as a huge amount, horizontally situated inbetween user names, which propagates the length of the webpage.

The question "[Attempting to use too long tag breaks popup](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/304247/attempting-to-use-too-long-tag-breaks-popup)" has comments suggesting that design issues are lower priority Bugs and an answer there offers a fix.

Comment: If someone from `Taumatawhakatangi­hangakoauauotamatea­turipukakapikimaunga­horonukupokaiwhen­uakitanatahu` puts that in their profile, and it's truncated, I don't think that's really *discrimination*. It's more just being reasonable with technical limitations. I think checking locations against known places is both overkill (not really necessary) and very hard to do right, since locations are manually typed (spelling it differently, punctuation, etc. could mess it up)