# Attempting to use too long tag breaks popup

Tags: bug, tags, design

If you try to add a tag with too long name, site will give you an error in popup. In some cases text in the popup overflows the boundaries:

> [image: toooo loooong tttttttag]

Comment: The error message is clear enough. Really no need for SE to waste time on this.

Comment: @ShadowWizard [they don’t like to fix design issues](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/design+bug+-status-completed+-status-bydesign+-status-declined+-status-norepro+-status-deferred+-status-planned+-status-review+-status-reproduced?sort=votes&pageSize=50).

Comment: As of 2019, the error message has been moved below the tag entry box and is now as wide as the box itself. However, a sufficiently long tag name can still trigger the overflow.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A simple:

```css
.message-text { word-wrap: break-word }
```

should fix this issue easily enough:

> [image: Screnshot]

Comment: It's a pity that this will never happen.