# Inbox message is not truncated properly

Tags: bug, design, global-inbox

Message with a long word, i.e. without spaces or dashes, is not truncated properly in inbox popup:

> [image: inbox]

This message from mobile web for comparing:

> [image: minbox]

I’m pretty sure that this behavior could be be fixed same way as for another issue: [Attempting to use too long tag breaks popup](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/304247/339911)

Comment: Probably it stayed on 0 score and got auto deleted by the Roomba.

Comment: Anyway... really can't be more minor than that. Nothing is broken, nothing is wrong. Why truncate it? :)

Comment: @ShadowtheHedgehogWizard “w” is outside the gray box, i.e. there is should be margin.