# Location forced to be on a single line broke my user profile

Tags: bug

Since a few minutes or hours (I guess since the programmers tried to fix the bug that caused the location to have an enormous amount of vertical space), the location is now enforced to be displayed on a single line. This broke my user profile. The picture is compressed sideways as shown on the following screenshot.

[image]

Comment: No repro in Chrome/Win10

Comment: I can reproduce this problem on firefox/mac osx

Comment: There you are! :P [Long user locations without a space causes the “user page” to display weird](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/281955/long-user-locations-without-a-space-causes-the-user-page-to-display-weird/316145#316145) add a couple of spaces between those jumble of symbols